# Is it appropriate to use the OpenERP 6.1 XMLRPC gateway for a web front-end?

Tags: odoo

We have been tasked to build a public web front-end on top of an OpenERP 6.1 backend. I have determined with a proof of concept that this will be possible using the XMLRPC gateway (after some CORS configuration). What we don't know is whether this is a good idea.

- Is OpenERP intended to be used in this way?
- Will the OpenERP & its XMLRPC gateway scale well enough as a web backend?
- What is an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a modern, open and full featured ERP solution OpenERP installations tend to contain considerable amount of valuable data not only for internal use but also for sharing trough other portals as the company web site, parters web sites etc.

To answer your questions:

> Is OpenERP intended to be used in this way?

It's more than normal to integrate OpenERP with external applications trough some integration interface. OpenERP is a rich application and the use of it's functionality and data outside the OpenERP client could be only of great value.

> Will the OpenERP & its XMLRPC gateway scale well enough as a web
>   backend?

The right way for cross-platform integration with OpenERP is using XMLRPC. This approach will scale as well as the OpenERP's web client scales (if configured to communication trough XMLRPC). I mean that you should take care about the performance but if you are not using complex functionality as closing accounting year you should be OK.

> What is an alternative?

If you are integrating from Python code the alternative is NetRPC. It's faster but seems to be Python specific as the protocol is mostly based on serialization of Python objects.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough response.

Answer (score 0):

**Is OpenERP intended to be used in this way?**

OpenERP is an ERP software. so it would be preferable to use OpenERP as software, instead of framework. OpenERP is providing customisation of its web client, So you can customise it as per your requirements instead of developing new one.

**Will the OpenERP & its XMLRPC gateway scale well enough as a web backend?**

Yes. You can create XMLRPC connector, to access OpenERP server side methods.
e.g : [example OPENERP: XML-RPC WEB SERVICES](http://www.emoticode.net/python/openerp-xml-rpc-web-services-crud-example.html)

Hope, this will be helpful.

Comment: Understood regarding the preferable use of OpenERP. In this case, there is a need to integrate some of the data in the OpenERP instance with another web portal. It is not possible for the OpenERP instance to serve this purpose. Is there another approach that OpenERP provides for integrating content with external services?